# Caffe : layers debugging

Tags: python-3.x, caffe

I am importing (in python) an ONNX file with the onnx_backend written for the Caffe2 framework. But at the end, I don't get the result/classification that I was expecting. Thus, to troubleshoot what went wrong, I try to get as much as possible debugging information that I can.

The first and biggest help that I could get is to get the result after each and every layer (meaning, get the image once I applied the Caffe convolution). This way, I could compare with another result that I have. How could I get this information when I call : `outputs = onnx_caffe2.backend.run_model(model, [img])`?

And what kind of other debug information could I get to help me during my investigations?